# How to make a child element(drop down) visible if the parent is overflow:auto?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a child element which come as a drop down while clicking on it and the parent element with overflow:auto;(i need a vertical scroll bar, it has a fixed height).

Why the child element is hidden if has the property overflow set to auto to parent?

HTML:

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody">
    <table class="dataTable">
            <tr class="ListRow">
                <td class=" column-2 sorting_1">
                    <ul class="ui-corner-all">
                    <li class="cv-shortcut-link">test link 1</li>
                    <li class="cv-shortcut-link">test link 2</li>
                    <li class="cv-shortcut-link">test link 3</li>
                    <li class="cv-shortcut-link">test link 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ListRow">
                <td class=" column-2 sorting_1">
                    parent list
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ListRow">
                <td class=" column-2 sorting_1">
                    parent list
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dataTables_scrollBody{height: auto;
    max-height: 80px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100px;}
    .ListRow {
    background-color: #EDF0F2;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: left;
}
.ListRow td {
    padding: 2px 3px;
}
.ui-corner-all{ border:green solid 1px;}
.ui-corner-all li{ list-style:none;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DHW9x/

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by hidden ? It's complete invisible or getting cutoff from screen..

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt appear to match your question content..

Comment: U can see in the screen shot, Drop down is cut off from the screen because parent div has the overflow: auto to make it scrollable.

Comment: @SW4..http://jsfiddle.net/yjv3v/1/  here is the entire code..dont know will it help to you..as there is so much code

Comment: Why don't you scroll to the bottom? Then the dropdown should be fully visible

Comment: I don't get what result you are expecting. You can still scroll to dropdown list to make it visible, so what is your issue?

Comment: You'll have to drop out any position relative that is inside `.dataTables_scrollBody ` and is a parent of this tooltip type box. Essentially means that you have to use javascript to position the tooltip, if you want to show it on outside/top of the scrollable div.

Comment: [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/vkCp7/) - [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/vkCp7/1/) The only thing I did different in example 2 was that I removed the position relatives from parent elements. --- Jquery UI `position` is very simple to use: http://jqueryui.com/position/